# Retrieve access_token from console log using Mocha

Tags: javascript, api, mocha.js, chai, web-api-testing

I can get the entire response log using console.log(res) but can't retrieve access_token from it. The response containing access_token looks like this:

```
    accept: [Array],
      'content-length': [Array]
    }
  },
  text: '{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJS....
```

I've tried the following:

```
 .end(  function (res, err, access_token, refresh_token) {
      
       if (err) console.error(err);
       else {
      
      console.log(res)
      expect(res).to.have.status(200);
       
       //console.log(res.body)
       const token = JSON.stringify.access_token;
      // token = res.access_token;
       console.log(token)

      //  let accessToken = await auth.getAccessToken();
      //  console.log(accessToken);
      //  assert(accessToken != null, 'token is null');
       

       //var token = body.access_token
       //console.log(token + "see on token");
      // console.log(`options.access_token: ${options.access_token}`);
```

[This is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxLsB.png)

UPDATE: By using the below code, parsing and using stringify I'm able to log out the token, but I'm still not able to use the parsed in the next request as header, getting undefined

```
chai.request(uaaUrl)
.post('/oauth/token')
.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
.set('Accept', '*/*',)
   .send(Authuser)   
   .end(function(err, res, body) {      
       const eurotoken = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.body.access_token));
       console.log('parsedd token', eurotoken);
       expect(res).to.have.status(200)
       done();
})




it('./health', (done) => {
    let eurotoken;
      chai.request(euro_url)
          .get('/request-statuses')
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
          .set('Accept', '*/*',)
          .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${eurotoken}` )
          .end(  function (res, err, body) {  
          if (err) console.error(err);
          else {
            expect(res).to.have.status(200)           
            done();
               }
            done();
        })
        });
```

Comment: what is this line: `const token = JSON.stringify.access_token;` ?

Comment: Can you just use res.body.access_token ?

Comment: @TLd res.body.access_token gives me the entire log output, not just access_token

Comment: Then you should parse the result : JSON.parse(res.body) and retrieve the access_token key

Comment: @Tld Thanks for your reply! I'm trying this var token = JSON.parse(res.body);
          console.log('result was parsed', access_token); and still getting the entire log

Comment: What's the output of the token ? And not access_token ? You should update your code with more details so people can help

Comment: @TLd following your advice I parsed the log output, but turns out it also needed to be translated into string, so this works `var eurotoken = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.body.access_token)); ` yet still when I try to use it in ` `header .set({Authorization: "Bearer " + eurotoken})`  I'm getting ` Authorization: Bearer undefined ` So I'm almost there.

Comment: Can you upload some code on github or on your post ? It's very hard to help you without much details

Comment: @TLd I uploaded some code on my post

Comment: It's clearer with more code. You declare eurotoken with a const in your test. So the variable will only be accessible inside the scope  of your function.
you should just define the : let euroToken; at the top of your file and remove the other variable déclaration. And in your first test instead of const eurotoken, simply do eurotoken =

Comment: Again it's very hard to explain clearly. Next time use github with a minimum reproductible example. You would have your answer 100 Times faster